# About $u_{n+1}=\sqrt{1+\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n}u_k\right)^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $(u_n) $ be a sequence such that
$$u_{n+1}=\sqrt{1+\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n}u_k\right)^2}$$
where $u_0>0$.

I was first asked to show that there exists a unique angle $\theta_n \in \left] 0;\pi/2\right]$ such that
$$u_n = \frac{1}{\sin(\theta_n)} $$
I've shown by induction that $u_n>1$ and hence I have the result. However, I need to deduce $\theta_n$! I've shown that
$$\frac{1}{\tan\left(\theta_{n+1}\right)}-\frac{1} {\tan\left(\theta_{n}\right)} =u_n=\frac{1}{\sin\left(\theta_{n}\right)} $$
My intuition was to sum this relation to obtain $1/\tan(\theta_{n+1})=... $ but I didn't find a nice expression for $\theta_n$, any hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have
$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{\tan(\theta_{n+1})}&=\frac{1}{\tan(\theta_{n})}+\frac{1}{\sin(\theta_{n})}\\
&=\frac{\cos(\theta_{n})+1}{\sin(\theta_{n})}\\
&=\frac{2\cos^2\left(\frac{\theta_{n}}{2}\right)}{2\sin\left(\frac{\theta_{n}}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\theta_{n}}{2}\right)}\\
&=\frac{1}{\tan\left(\frac{\theta_{n}}{2}\right)}\
\end{align}$$

So
$$\theta_{n+1}=\frac{\theta_{n}}{2}$$